# Pause or Break using Google Text to Speech

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I am trying out the text to speech for the first time using a storyboard created in Microsoft Word. When placed in text to speech via the computer it doesn't allow for pauses. How do I add a pause between 2 sentences and how do I increase the pause duration?